# Disable Lint warning "The view name suggests this is a number but it does not include a numeric inputType"

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings, adt, lint

I've searched through the list of warnings in the Lint Error Checking preferences but can't find it. The list is a bit too long to check every warning to see if it's the one I want, and filtering the warnings with `name`, `number`, `numeric`, `inputType`, etc, does not bring up the warning. Hovering the mouse over the warning doesn't seem to provide the **warning ID**.

I have a good reason for using a text `inputType` for a variable with number in its name, which is that I want to log in to a server which uses a number as a login ID, therefore I need the number as a string. I don't really like having the warning there, I'd like to disable that specific warning if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties --> Android Lint Preferences --> Usability --> TextFields and select Ignore in the Severity box.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it in the XML, by adding `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TextFields"` to your XML tag.  (If you are going to do it more than once, you should of course put the xmlns part in a parent tag, or even in the top level tag, so you don't have to repeat that every time).  The advantage of this is that you can suppress it for *only* that instance of it, so that way if it happens again (by accident) you still get warned.